# NavBar Issues - Hover and Spacing

Tags: html, css, hover, spacing

I currently have 2 issues with the navbar I'm working on. The first issue is regarding the hover feature on navbar links.My intention is to have an underline appear in the color purple (#9908ff) when a user hovers over the links in the navbar. However, the hover code in the CSS is not functioning as expected.

The second issue is regarding the alignment of the 3 sections in the navbar. I have the logo on the left, navbar links in the middle and buttons on the right. The challenge arises when I attempt to add space between the two buttons on the right, aiming for a more balanced spacing between the sections. Currently, the buttons on the right appear very cramped together. How can I resolve this issue?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fake News and Critical Thinking</title>

    <!-- fontawesome -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/952dcc46a8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- google font import; montserrat -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- google font import; gabarito -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gabarito:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- header -->
    <header>
        <div class="nav-container">

        <img src="/img/IV-3.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Current Affairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class ="nav-btns">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a></li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
        
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #0b0e16;
}

.logo {
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

a {
    font-family: 'Gabarito', cursive;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-links {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    
}

.nav-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}

.nav-links li a:hover,
.nav-links li a.active {
    color: #ece0ff;
}

.nav-links li a:hover::after,
.nav-links li a.active::after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background: #9908ff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try this code and let me know if it resolves your issues
.nav-btns {
    width: 60px;
}

.nav-links li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9908ff;
}

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a ton!

The only issue left is nav buttons. The spacing between the two buttons is still an issue. They look cramped but moved 60px left from page margin. @Ashish

Comment: For spacing between the nav buttons you can use: 
.nav-btns a {
    text-indent: 11px;
}

.nav-btns {
    width: 70px;
}

Comment: It worked as well. Tysm! 
Also, I tried making the indent bigger than 11 px and that pushes it more towards the page margin. Is there a way to avoid that? @Ashish

Comment: If you increase the width it will help you maintain the space between the nav links and page margin like:
.nav-btns {
    width: 91px;
}

Comment: Also please click on this comment if you feel my comments are useful in fixing your issue

Comment: I see. I also changed 'padding: 10px 0;' to 'padding: 10px 20px;' in .nav-container and that solved the issue by creating space on both sides of the page. Thanks a lot for your help. Would suggest you answer it instead of leaving comments so you can get upvotes for your helpful answers :)

Comment: I posted an answer as per your recommendation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For spacing between the nav buttons you can use:

```
.nav-btns a { text-indent: 11px; } .nav-btns { width: 70px; }
```

For underline menus on hover you can use:

```
.nav-links li a:hover { border-bottom: 1px solid #9908ff; }
```